# Illustrated hardcover book of folk tales for children, with a wizard on the cover

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

A large, hardcover, illustrated children's book with a wizard on the front, facing the reader staff raised and casting a spell. It contained a number of folk tales for children.

The stories included versions of the following:

- [The Sorcerer's Apprentice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorcerer%27s_Apprentice). A lazy wizard's apprentice conjures an imp/goblin to help him with chores, but it goes terribly wrong and the goblin almost floods the place with multiple barrels of water from the river while trying to wash the floor, before the wizard arrives and banishes him.
- A story about a boy who outsmarts a Troll by wagering he can [eat more porridge than him in a competition](https://www.writefairytales.com/2012/07/fairy-tale-friday-the-ash-lad-who-had-an-eating-match-with-a-troll-for-lisa/), the troll doesn't see that the boy is scooping the porridge into a knapsack under the table instead of eating it, and then pretends to slit his belly when it gets too full. The troll asks if this doesn't hurt and he says no, so he attempts this and kills himself.
- I *think* there was also a story about a boy who caught a leprechaun and demanded the pot of gold, the leprechaun said it was buried under a thistle, and the boy put a red handkerchief around it to mark it, while he went home to get a spade. When he comes back, every thistle in the field has a red handkerchief over it.

I got this book while 10-12 years old, mid 1990's, and for the life of me I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Hi Aaron, can you tell us more about it? Was it illustrated? What kind of outfit did the wizard on the over have? Can you give an estimate of when it was published (such a cover sounds very 1980s to me)? I presume it was in English, but can you verify? How many stories did it contain?

Comment: These sound very much like traditional folktales (the Troll eating contest is a traditional Norwegian, Leprechaun trickery is traditional Irish), so it could be any one of many collections. Quite possibly something like "fairytales from around the world". Jane Yolen is famous for these sorts of things - try a google on her name.

Comment: @Joachim it was a large, illustrated book for older children 10-12 years, published ~1990-1995 I think, and in English. It contained about 8 stories. The Wizard had a colourful outfit, and I believe he was standing in a grassy field, but my memory might not be great here!

Comment: @bob1 I will also try looking for that name, thanks!